# How to start a process with a subset of user permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, powershell

Let's assume I have a process a.exe that according to its manual/specification does not write any files, how would I start it without write permission?

Closest I can think of is creating a user with select permissions (i.e. without write) and start the process as that user. But I would much rather have a launcher script or similar that can easily be used by other users with minimal effort and system impact.